# android mediaplayer class with better time resolution

Tags: android, media-player

I have a music application that needs to synchronize certain things with music playback.

Currently, I use the MediaPlayer class to do this.

What I've found is that when I use the MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), which is supposed to return the current position in milliseconds, I sometimes get the exact same result if I make two successive calls too close.  So I have to put a delay between the calls.

I've also found that the results are wildly inaccurate.  To fix this, I have a running buffer and I calculate the average time-lapse between my calls to MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition().  After a few seconds, I get a reasonably stable value - and my application performs quite smoothly and accurately.

Is there a better media player class I could use?  One where I could get more accurate time-position of a song currently playing?